# What was this dubious medical facility by the salt lakes?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

When Herman and Olga were trying to straighten out the paperwork for the gas station, they realized they need to track down a director of an oil depot for some help with some paperwork. However, they encountered a problem:

> After making a few calls, Olga ascertained that things would be even more complicated than she'd assumed. It turned out that our pillar of the community didn't actually live in the community anymore. He had moved to a medical facility by the salt lakes that were a few dozen kilometers away from here. We had no clue what condition he would be in, what kind of treatment he was getting, or even whether there was any scientific basis for him being out there in the first place.

The main points I could gather from the text were:

1. The person who moved there was somewhat prominent in the community
2. It's by some salt lakes (presumably placed there in the belief that it would be a healthful environment)
3. The director moved there (i.e. he was no longer living in the community), so he was evidently there long-term
4. There may or may not have been an actual scientific basis for him being there in the first place
5. It was later described as an "old, time-worn sanitarium"
6. Olga claimed that he was "practically being held there against his will" (although I suspect that this claim was self-serving)
7. Herman believed that one of the "patients" had actually been dead for several days (although again I'm not sure if this was actually true)

What kind of place was this? Are there facilities like this in Ukraine, and if so, what are they like?

Comment: [Have you tried Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=salt+water+sanatorium+ukraine)?

Comment: @StuartF Fair point... so there really are places like that.